# IntelliJ signs me out from Github

Tags: github, intellij-idea

Why is Intellij constantly logging of my Github account every time I close IntelliJ?
I also tried to use the token to login, but even that didn't help.
[Message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxws.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to your passwords option: `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`. You need to change it from Do not save, forget passwords after restart to In native Keychain/In KeePass.